# Js jquery recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I want to make a recursive function. Consider I have a function named setoptions and I need to set 2 options so what I will do is call my function twice like this.

```
setoptions ("ajax",true);
setoptions ("lamda",false);
```

So to avoid it I should be able to write a function in a way that I can define multiple options like

```
setoptions({
    "lamda": false,
    "ajax": true
});
```

This is same as jquery`s attr function. 
like

```
$("#ff").attr("href","#");
$("#ff").attr("data-type","blue");
// can be used as 
$("#ff").attr({
    "data-type": "blue",
    "href": "#"
});
```

Kindly do not provide workarounds as I need to understand such recursion for learning.

**Basic setOption function:**

```
  var setOption =  function (val1, val2) {
    $.someplugin(val1, val);
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure this should be called *recusion*...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function setOption(){
  if(arguments.length==2)
    window.arguments[0] = arguments[1];
   else {
     for(var key in arguments[0]){
       setOption(key,arguments[0][key];
     }
   }
 }
```

**Edit:** I used window object, because I dunno where your values have to be set. So you might have to modify the if body statement in your code.

**Edit2:** As only this is can be called a recursion for me, this would be my approach. If you want to call a plugin, then I'd design that plugin to act recursively.

****EDIT 3 ****
Yeah I think something like this.
Do note that it is still not recursive.console.log() line should not repeat.

```
 var setOption = function () {
     if (arguments.length == 2) {
         console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
     } else if (jQuery.isPlainObject(arguments[0])) {
         for (var key in arguments[0]) {
             console.log(key, arguments[0][key]);
         }

     }
 }
 //USAGE:
 setOption({
     "href": "#",
     "data": "123",
 });

 setOption("cell", true);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var setOption =  function (data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    $.someplugin(key, data[key]);
  }
};
```

Comment: This wont take care of data on format like ```setOption("key","value");```

Answer (score 0):

This is I came up with. Let me know if there is a better approach.
This is now true recursive.

```
var setOption = function () {
     if (jQuery.isPlainObject(arguments[0])) {
         for (var key in arguments[0]) {
             setOption(key, arguments[0][key]);
         }
     } else if (arguments.length == 2) {
         console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
     }
}

//USAGE:
setOption({
  "href": "#",
  "data": "123",
});

setOption("cell", true);
```